# Why is JFrame blank in one case but not the other? (Simple SwingWorker example)

Tags: java, swing, jframe

===============================================

Adding this here since it's too long for a comment:

I can see I was unclear. When running MaintTest/main, the JFrame with Test button is not the problem. The JFrame which gets displayed when you click the test button is the problem.

Commenting out the FileUtils.copyURLToFile try block makes the 2nd JFrame display so briefly it's not clear whether it shows the label and progbar or not. (The initial JFrame with the Test button appears normally, when I click the Test button, the 2nd JFrame appears for an instant and goes away. The JFrame with the Test button remains, as expected. I don't reproduce "a Test button 6 times in a row". That sounds like things are set up wrong maybe?)

Yes copyURLToFile is blocking, but I start the concurrent display of the 2nd JFrame before I call copyURLToFile, so shouldn't it run in a separate thread anyway? I have a reason to know trhat it does. In the original application from which this code is derived, the 2nd JFrame displays as desired *sometimes*.

JFrame displaying sometimes is always answered by saying setVisible has to be called last, but that does not address my situation. This appears to have something to do with concurrency and Swing that I don't understand.

===============================================

Usually I can find the answers via google (more often than not at SO). I must be missing something here.

I've whittled this down to a small portion of my actual code and am still not enlightened. Sorry if it's still a little large, but it's hard to condense it further.

There are 3 java files. This references commons-io-2.5.jar. I'm coding/running in Eclipse Neon.

If I run `ProgressBar`/`main()` I see the `JFrame` contents. If I run `MainTest`/`main()` I don't. Here are the 3 files (please excuse some indentation anomalies -- the SO UI and I didn't agree on such things):

### `MainTest`

```
public class MainTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    MainFrame mainFrame = new MainFrame();
}

}
```

### `MainFrame`

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

JButton jButton = new JButton();

public MainFrame() {
    // Set up the content pane.
    Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    jButton.setText("Test");
    jButton.setActionCommand("Test");
    jButton.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(jButton);
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    Toolkit tk;
    Dimension screenDims;
    tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    screenDims = tk.getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation((screenDims.width - this.getWidth()) / 2, (screenDims.height - this.getHeight()) / 2);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void downloadExecutable(String str) {
    URL url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://pegr-converter.com/download/test.jpg");
    } catch (MalformedURLException exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected exception: " + exc.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    if (url != null) {
        String[] options = { "OK", "Change", "Cancel" };
        int response = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
        File selectedFolder = new File(getDownloadDir());
        File selectedLocation = new File(selectedFolder, str + ".jpg");
        while (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            selectedLocation = new File(selectedFolder, str + ".jpg");
            String msgStr = str + ".jpg will be downloaded to the following location:\n"
                    + selectedLocation.toPath();
            response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, msgStr, "Pegr input needed",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
            if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                // Prompt for file selection.
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(selectedFolder);
                fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                selectedFolder = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            }
        }
        if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            int size = 0;
            URLConnection conn;
            try {
                conn = url.openConnection();
                size = conn.getContentLength();
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
            }
            File destination = new File(selectedFolder, str + ".jpg");
            ProgressBar status = new ProgressBar("Downloading " + str + ".jpg", destination, size);
            try {
                FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination, 10000, 300000);
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Download failed.");
                return;
            }
            status.close();
        }
    }
}

public static String getDownloadDir() {
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File downloadDir = new File(home + "/Downloads/");
    if (downloadDir.exists() && !downloadDir.isDirectory()) {
        return home;
    } else {
        downloadDir = new File(downloadDir + "/");
        if ((downloadDir.exists() && downloadDir.isDirectory()) || downloadDir.mkdirs()) {
            return downloadDir.getPath();
        } else {
            return home;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    downloadExecutable("test");
}

}
```

### `ProgressBar`

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JProgressBar;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class ProgressBar {

private String title;
private File outputFile;
private int size;
private ProgressTimerTask task;

JFrame frame;
JLabel jLabelProgressTitle;
JProgressBar jProgressBarProportion;

public ProgressBar(String title, File output, int size) {
    this.title = title;
    this.outputFile = output;
    this.size = size;
    frame = new JFrame("BoxLayoutDemo");

    jProgressBarProportion = new JProgressBar();
    jProgressBarProportion.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));

    jLabelProgressTitle = new JLabel();
    jLabelProgressTitle.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
    jLabelProgressTitle.setText("Progress");
    jLabelProgressTitle.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 50));

    //Set up the content pane.
    Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jLabelProgressTitle.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    contentPane.add(jLabelProgressTitle);
    jProgressBarProportion.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    contentPane.add(jProgressBarProportion);

    setup();

    task = new ProgressTimerTask(this, outputFile, size);
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 500);
}

private void setup() {
    Toolkit tk;
    Dimension screenDims;

    frame.setTitle("Test");

    tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    screenDims = tk.getScreenSize();
    frame.setLocation((screenDims.width - frame.getWidth()) / 2, (screenDims.height - frame.getHeight()) / 2);

    jLabelProgressTitle.setText(title);
    jProgressBarProportion.setVisible(true);
    jProgressBarProportion.setMinimum(0);
    jProgressBarProportion.setMaximum(size);
    jProgressBarProportion.setValue((int) outputFile.length());

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public void close() {
    task.cancel();
    frame.dispose();
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    ProgressBar progBar = new ProgressBar("Test Title", new File(MainFrame.getDownloadDir() + "test.jpg"), 30000);
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    progBar.close();
}

}

class ProgressTimerTask extends TimerTask {

ProgressBar frame;
File outputFile;
int size;

public ProgressTimerTask(ProgressBar progressBar, File outputFile, int size) {
    this.frame = progressBar;
    this.outputFile = outputFile;
    this.size = size;
}

public void run() {
    frame.jProgressBarProportion.setValue((int) outputFile.length());
    System.out.println("Running");
}

}
```

Comment: Try starting both GUIs on the Event Dispatch Thread, and take out the sleep in the main method.

Comment: Your `mainFrame` works fine for me

Comment: Did you try it after commenting out the `FileUtils` and related functionality? I did and saw a `Test` button 6 times in a row.

Comment: I can tell you, that you probably won't see the `ProgressBar` frame because the `FileUtils.copyURLToFile` will block until it's finished, in that case, you really should be using a `SwingWorker`

Comment: The sleep is in the case that works, so I believe that is irrelevant to why the other case (with no sleep) doesn't work.

Comment: @MadProgrammer, are you saying you can run MainTest/main() and click the Test button, click OK and download the file and you see a progress bar display and advance from zero to full size? In other words, you reproduce the desired behavior and not the problem? That would suggest it's system/platform/debugger dependent.

Comment: I'm going to read up about SwingWorker, though, as explained in my edit, I don't see why copyURLToFile blocking should be a problem.

Comment: I  read as far as checking isEventDispatchThread(), and sure enough when I put a println into my downloadExecutable(), I get:javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread=true so I think further reading may start to make sense of this for me, thanks @MadProgrammer. Time to return to the 3-ring circus that is my life. I'll try to summarize later.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MadProgrammer for this comment:

> I can tell you, that you probably won't see the ProgressBar frame because the FileUtils.copyURLToFile will block until it's finished, in that case, you really should be using a SwingWorker

I read up about SwingWorker at the tutorial https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html and subsequently modified my MainFrame.java module to look like this:

```
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
JButton jButton = new JButton();
static ProgressBar status;
static URL url;

public MainFrame() {
    // Set up the content pane.
    Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
    contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    jButton.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
    jButton.setText("Test");
    jButton.setActionCommand("Test");
    jButton.addActionListener(this);
    contentPane.add(jButton);
    setup();
}

private void setup() {
    Toolkit tk;
    Dimension screenDims;
    tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    screenDims = tk.getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation((screenDims.width - this.getWidth()) / 2, (screenDims.height - this.getHeight()) / 2);

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.pack();
    this.setVisible(true);
}

public static void downloadExecutable(String str) {
    url = null;
    try {
        url = new URL("http://pegr-converter.com/download/test.jpg");
    } catch (MalformedURLException exc) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Unexpected exception: " + exc.getMessage());
        return;
    }
    if (url != null) {
        String[] options = { "OK", "Change", "Cancel" };
        int response = JOptionPane.NO_OPTION;
        File selectedFolder = new File(getDownloadDir());
        File selectedLocation = new File(selectedFolder, str + ".jpg");
        while (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            selectedLocation = new File(selectedFolder, str + ".jpg");
            String msgStr = str + ".jpg will be downloaded to the following location:\n"
                    + selectedLocation.toPath();
            response = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, msgStr, "Pegr input needed",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, options, options[0]);
            if (response == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                // Prompt for file selection.
                JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(selectedFolder);
                fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                selectedFolder = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            }
        }
        if (response == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            int size = 0;
            URLConnection conn;
            try {
                conn = url.openConnection();
                size = conn.getContentLength();
            } catch (IOException exc) {
                System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
            }
            //System.out.println("javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread=" + javax.swing.SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
            File destination = new File(selectedFolder, str + ".jpg");
            status = new ProgressBar("Downloading " + str + ".jpg", destination, size);
            SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {
                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    try {
                        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(url, destination, 10000, 300000);
                    } catch (IOException exc) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Download failed.");
                    }
                    return null;
                }
                public void done() {
                    status.close();
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        }
    }
}

public static String getDownloadDir() {
    String home = System.getProperty("user.home");
    File downloadDir = new File(home + "/Downloads/");
    if (downloadDir.exists() && !downloadDir.isDirectory()) {
        return home;
    } else {
        downloadDir = new File(downloadDir + "/");
        if ((downloadDir.exists() && downloadDir.isDirectory()) || downloadDir.mkdirs()) {
            return downloadDir.getPath();
        } else {
            return home;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    downloadExecutable("test");
}

}
```

This worked beautifully.